# Is there a simple way of deriving the equation for the average size of subsets of consecutive numbers from $1$ to $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

For example, the subsets of consecutive numbers from $1$ to $3$ are
$$
\{1\}, \quad 
\{2\}, \quad 
\{3\}, \quad 
\{1, 2\}, \quad 
\{2, 3\}, \quad 
\text{and } \quad \{1, 2, 3\}.
$$
Note: $\{1, 3\}$ is omitted because the numbers $1$ and $3$ are not consecutive.

The average size in this case is
$$
\dfrac{3 \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot 2 + 3}{6} = \dfrac{5}{3}. 
$$
It was not difficult to come up with a closed algebraic expression in terms of arithmetic series and sum of squares. I can show my work if anyone wants to see it. Applying the associated formulas and then simplifying gives a very simple expression:
$$
\dfrac{n}{3} + \dfrac{2}{3}. 
$$
You can see how it works for the case of $n=3$. Is there a simple way of deriving this formula without having to simplify much more complex expressions?

Comment: There are $n+1-k$ subsets of size $k,$ so the value is $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n(n+1-k)k}{\sum_{k=1}^n (n+1-k)}$$

Comment: Working it out in my head, the average is $$n+1-\frac{2n+1}{3}=\frac{n+2}3.$$ But I'd need to check that.

Comment: I have got the same result, using the formulas for [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) and [square pyramidal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number)

Comment: ... and I don't think that it gets much simpler than that. You have to apply the formula for the "average size" at some time, which necessarily leads to the formula in Thomas' first comment. Apart from using the well-known formulas for triangular numbers and square pyramidal numbers, I do not see a way of simplifying the calculations that give us the final result. Is this simpler than what you have done? We cannot know what you are referring to when you say "much more complex expressions."

Answer (score 2):

Possibly simpler inductive proof:

First remark that there are $\frac {n(n+1)}2$ good subsets attached to $n$.  This follows immediately from the fact that there are exactly $n$ which contain $n$, exactly $n-1$ others which contain $n-1$ and so on.

the desired result is easily verified for small $n$.  Suppose it's known up to $n-1$.

For $n$, once again,  there are exactly $n$ good subsets which contain $n$. The total length of these is  $\frac {n(n+1)}2$.  The other good subsets are attached to $n-1$.  Inductively, we know there are $\frac {n(n-1)}2$ of these and that they have average length $\frac {n+1}3$.  Thus the average length attached to $n$ is $$\left(\frac {n(n+1)}2+\frac {n(n-1)}2\times \frac {n+1}3\right)\times \frac 2{n(n+1)}=\frac {n+2}3$$ as desired

Comment: Nicely done, but since the proof is by induction, it still leaves open the question of how to initially derive the equation.  It just seems odd that all the square terms drop out, leaving a simple linear equation.

Comment: @user1153980  Yeah, there's probably a simpler combinatorial argument.  If I think of one, I'll post it.

Comment: The solution divided by n converges to 1/3.  Why 1/3?  Or is that like asking why four for the Four Color Theorem?

Comment: Well, the expected distance between two points (uniformly chosen on $[0,1]$) is $\frac 13$, so that part is not surprising.

Comment: This is the center of mass calculation for a  symmetrical stair-step pattern, and thus could perhaps be determined  quickly by a geometrical argument.

Comment: lulu's remark makes good sense.  If you divide the unit interval into n equal divisions then the sizes of subsets of consecutive integers from 1 to n  maps to distances covered by adjacent intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Take a circle of $n+2$ balls, insert three bars at three different places between consecutive balls.
Pick one of the bars, and label the balls clockwise from $0$ to $n+1$.
The random interval is the set of balls between the other two bars.
By symmetry, the average length is a third of $n+2$.

Comment: I like the reasoning behind that, but can't quite picture it.  It must be the case that there will be at least 2 balls not between the two rods and at least one ball between them.  That may very well be the case.  I just can't visualize it.